# How can I remove elements in this project with backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am making a project in Backbone.js In this project I can click on the search terms to add them to the tracked foods list. After that I have an option to add the food to a meal or remove the food. I cannot get the remove button to work when I click remove on a food item in the tracked foods list.

Here is a JS fiddle with my code: https://jsfiddle.net/Tiquismiquis/2nLezvmg/11/

Here is my JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(function(){

var Food = Backbone.Model.extend({

        defaults:{
            title: 'no information found',
            brand: 'no information found',
            calories: 'no information found',
            day: 'all'
        }
});

var AllFoods = Backbone.Collection.extend({model: Food});



var SearchList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    initialize: function(){
        this.bind("reset", function(model, options){
        console.log("Inside event");
        console.log(model);
        });
    },
    //** 1. Function "parse" is a Backbone function to parse the response properly
    parse:function(response){
        //** return the array inside response, when returning the array
        //** we left to Backone populate this collection
        return response.hits;
    }

});

// The main view of the application
var App = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: 'body',

    events: {
    "input #searchBox" : "prepCollection",
    "click #listing li" : "track",
    "click #add": "addClicked",
    "click .destroy": "destroy"
    },

    initialize: function () {

        this.model = new SearchList();
        this.foods = new AllFoods();
        this.prepCollection =_.debounce(this.prepCollection, 1000);
        this.$total = $('#total span');
        this.$list = $('#listing');
        this.$tracked =$('#tracked');
        this.model.on('destroy', this.remove, this);


    },

    addClicked: function(e) {
        var $target = $(e.currentTarget).parent();
       var $selected = $target.find('#mySelect').val();

        var location = $target.attr('data-id');
        var currentFood = this.foods.get(location);


        switch($selected) {
            case 'Breakfast':
                $('#breakfast').append(currentFood.get('html'));
                break;
            case 'Lunch':
                $('#lunch').append(currentFood.get('html'));
                break;
            case 'Dinner':
                $('#dinner').append(currentFood.get('html'));
                break;
            case 'Snack':
                $('#snack').append(currentFood.get('html'));
                break;
            default:
                alert("Error: try again");
        }




    },

    destroy: function () {
       this.model.destroy();
    },

    prepCollection: function(){
        var name = $('input').val();
        var newUrl = "https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/" + name + "?results=0%3A20&cal_min=0&cal_max=50000&fields=item_name,brand_name,item_id,nf_calories&appId=26952a04&appKey=33b9262901d0068d4895736b5af19805";

       if (name == ""){
        this.$list.html("")
       }
       else{
        this.model.url = newUrl;
        this.model.fetch({
            success: function (response, xhr) {
                console.log("Inside success");
                console.log(response.toJSON());
            },
            error: function (errorResponse) {
                console.log(errorResponse)
            }
        });
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'sync', this.render);
       }

    },

    track: function(e){


        this.listenTo(this.foods, 'add', this.renderfoods);

        var $target = $(e.currentTarget);
        var item_name = $target.attr('data-name');
        var brand_name = $target.attr('data-brand');
        var calorieString = $target.attr('data-calories');
        var calorieAmt = parseFloat(calorieString);
        var foodid = $target.attr('data-id');

        var chooseday ='<form>What meal was this part of?: <select id="mySelect"> <option value="Breakfast">Breakfast</option><option value="Lunch">Lunch</option><option value="Dinner">Dinner</option><option value="Snack">Snack</option></select></form><button id="add" type="button">Add To Meal</button><button class="destroy" type="button">Remove</button>';

        var trackedhtml = '<li'+' data-id='+'"'+ foodid +'"'+'>' +"<strong>" + item_name + '</strong>'+ ' ('+ brand_name + ')'+' - '+ calorieAmt + ' Calories' + chooseday + '</li>'


        this.foods.add(new Food({ id: foodid, title: item_name, brand: brand_name, calories: calorieAmt, html: trackedhtml}));

    },

    renderfoods: function() {
        var total = 0;
        var trackedhtml = '';

       this.foods.each(function(food){
            trackedhtml = trackedhtml + food.get('html');
            total += food.get('calories');
       },this)
        this.$tracked.html(trackedhtml);
         this.$total.html(total);



    },

    render: function(){
        var terms = this.model;
        var wordhtml = '';
        terms.each(function (term) {
            wordhtml = wordhtml + '<li' + ' data-id=' + '"' + term.get('_id') +'"'+' data-name=' + '"' + term.get('fields')['item_name'] +'"'+ ' data-brand='+'"' + term.get('fields')['brand_name'] + '"' + ' data-calories='+ '"' + term.get('fields')['nf_calories'] + '"' + '>' +"<strong>" + term.get('fields')["item_name"] + '</strong>'+ ' ('+ term.get('fields')["brand_name"] + ')'+' - '+ term.get('fields')["nf_calories"] + ' Calories' + '</li>'
        }, this);
        this.$list.html(wordhtml);

    }
});
       var app = new App();
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Food Guide App</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <h1>Interactive Food Guide</h1>
                <input type="text" id="searchBox"> <br/><br/>
                <ul id="listing"></ul>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <h1>Foods Tracked</h1>
                <ul id="tracked"></ul>
                <p id="total"><strong> total calories:</strong> <span>0</span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class=" text-center col-xs-12">
                <ul id="breakfast"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <ul id="lunch"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <ul id="dinner"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <ul id="snack"></ul>
            </div>
            <!-- TODO: Put food pyramid here -->
        </div>


    </div>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Backbone and Underscore -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.2.1/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <!-- apps functionality -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why are you destroying the model on clicking `.destroy` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is not backbone style, but if you want to remove from DOM, you can simply do :

```
destroy: function(e){
  var $li = $(e.currentTarget).closest('li')
  this.foods.remove($li.attr('data-id'));
  $li.remove();
  //recalculate calories & stuff
}
```

Working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/nitincool4urchat/2nLezvmg/15/

Comment: Yes, I have tried this but if you test it out, you can remove one but when you click on another element in the terms list the old one comes back plus the new one.

Comment: I think I must find a way to remove the model from the collection in order to remove it completley

Comment: Thank you, I came up with this solution before viewing yours and it looks much the same as your code. View my finished project here http://renniesb.github.io/food_guide/index.html